# I want my code to start automatically after sharepoint is restarted

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I implemented a feature that checks a list periodically. But when SharePoint is restarted it doesn't start automatically. I will have to manually deactivate and reactivate the feature to get it started again.

Is there a way to get sharepoint to start my code automatically it starts up?

Comment: I used a System.Timers.Timer object but I just found out that I should be using an SPJobDefinition and SPSchedule object which I'm trying to do now. Thanks

Comment: Check the status of your job in Central Administration (*Operations / Timer Job Definitions* and one more similar link). What kind of schedule do you use? Is OWS Timer service configured to start automatically?